# Guidance for using Syntax and Parameters in documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, syntax-section, parameters-section

I would like to see some guidance on how to use the Syntax and Parameters sections in documentation.

I was just now looking at a review that seemed to combine syntax and explanation. While I had the direct urge to reject, it also made me realise that I didn't have a clear idea how to use the Syntax and Parameters sections. It would be great if we had some guidance (or 'best of breed' examples) to link to so people can improve how these sections should be used

Comment: I haven't fully fleshed this thought out, but I'm inclining towards the idea that Syntax might be a section that we _don't always need_ to fill out. Unless it changes from the one-line format. Right now I see it being used for basically mini-examples, not really _syntax_ as such, and it's messy because the explanatory comments don't fit.

Comment: This is one of the things one expected the closed beta to flesh out...

Comment: I don't know about you, but I've yet to see anyone use the Parameters section at all.

Comment: Yes using parameter section is a great pain.

Answer (score -4):

There's guidance in the editor for these sections... that should probably also be available in review, now that I think about it.

[image]

[image]

The TL;DR of them is: use Syntax and Parameters to reduce duplication in examples.  If multiple examples have to explain some syntactic element (like a function call) or a value (which is typical a parameter to a function) then consider moving those to explanations.

Comment: I have read those, and they don't help me at all _"Use syntax to reduce duplication"_ How? _"explain the parameters used in syntax"_ again, how? The usages I have seen up to now seem to be a disjointed list of methods or code without explanation or if there was explanation it looked rather poor, as if explanation shouldn't be part of it. The separation between Syntax and Parameters hurts readability if there is a lot of syntax, etc etc.